# turning back to earlier version of Debian

Tags: debian

How can I downgrade from Debian 10 to 9? Is this even possible?

```
uname -a
Linux MilczarskiVon 4.19.0-21-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.249-2 (2022-06-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: All you need to know about downgrade in Debian is here https://wiki.debian.org/SystemDowngrade